# Logstash connection with Oracle wallet

Tags: oracle, jdbc, logstash, elastic-stack, oracle-wallet

I'm having issues connecting Logstash using Oracle wallet. I am getting an invalid login/password even though I am trying to connect through the wallet, without using said login/password.

```
[ERROR][logstash.inputs.jdbc ] Unable to connect to database. Tried 2 times {:error_message=>"Java::JavaSql::SQLException: ORA-01017 Invalid Username/Password"}
```

Here's my Logstash jdbc input file :

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_driver_library => "${ORACLE_HOME}/dmu/jlib/ojdbc10.jar,${ORACLE_HOME}/ucp/lib/ucp.jar,${ORACLE_HOME}/jlib/oraclepki.jar,${ORACLE_HOME}/jlib/osdt_cert.jar,${ORACLE_HOME}/jlib/osdt_core.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:/@name_high?TNS_ADMIN=${ORACLE_HOME}/network/admin/wallet"
        jdbc_user => ""
        schedule => "* * * * * *"
        statement => "SELECT * from table"
        connection_retry_attempts => 2
        connection_retry_attempts_wait_time => 5
        jdbc_pool_timeout => 20
        jdbc_validation_timeout => 600
    }
}
```

So I use the following drivers :

- `ojdbc10.jar`
- `ucp.jar`
- `oraclepki.jar`
- `osdt_cert.jar`
- `osdt_core.jar`
- I made sure every environement variable paths are correct, every access rights correctly set.
- I believe the connection string syntaxe is correct since it does find the tnsnames.ora and attempt a connexion to the right host, port, sid.
- I omitted the field jdbc_password in the jdbc input as it is not required and I don't want jdbc to think I want to use it. I left the jdbc_user field but empty as it is apparently required even though I'm trying not to use it.
- I'm able to connect to the database using sqlplus as follows:

  `sqlplus /@name_high`

Comment: When running "sqlplus /@name_high" on a remote machine, it ask me for the username/password, which is quite logical in my point of view since the wallet let's you connect to the database not to a particular schema. Are you connecting from the server?
To create a password-less connection take a look on: https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/comment/16789766/#Comment_16789766, you will need an external password store.

Comment: OS Auth: "sqlplus /", JDBC Thin driver does not support OS Auth. (At least it didn't). You may need to utilize the JDBC OCI "thick driver" or username/password for the thin one.

Answer (score 1):

So what I was missing was the java property wallet_location wich append to be the same path as the TNS_ADMIN in my case.

It needs to be loaded by the script that launch the JRE when starting Logstash as such :

-Doracle.net.wallet_location=${WALLET_PATH}

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the [blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/developers/post/ssl-connection-to-oracle-db-using-jdbc-tlsv12-jks-or-oracle-wallets-122-and-lower#Wallets) for steps with different versions of the driver. Also, you can refer to the [blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/developers/post/four-facets-of-database-connectivity-for-java-applications) to know different ways to set connection properties.